# Отклонение приложение в google play market

Tags: android, google-play

Здравствуйте.

Решил сделать неофициальный android клиент для одного сайта, так как официального у него нет, а пользоваться приложением будет удобнее.

Сайт является платёжной системой и каждый пользователь может создать апи аккаунт для управления кошельком.

На апи я и решил сделать приложение.

При запуске приложения первый раз,  открывалось webview с сайтом и пользователю нужно было войти в акк, чтобы отправился запрос на создание апи от юзера. В webview встраивался большой js, чтобы приложение могло понять, когдда пользователь вошёл в акк.

Далее приложение работало с апи через взятые данные.

Загрузил приложение, через несколько часов его отклонили по причине спама через webview

Естесственно, никакого спама приложение не отправляло, а просто отправляло запрос на сервер платёжной системы.

Я отправил аппеляцию, где описал, что это неофициальное приложение, никакого спама не отправляет и т.д.

К слову, везде в приложении и в описании в play market я выделял, что приложение неофициальное. И указывал, что оно само создаёт апи аккаунт.

Через 2 дня мне ответили и потребовали доказательства, что торговая марка платёжной системы принадлежит мне.

К слову, настоящее название платёжки я употребил 2 раза: в описании: "...неофициальный android клиент для платёжной системы ******..." И в самом приложении в том же контексте.

Название приложение было "My-******", где ****** -- название этой платёжной системы.
Т.е. торговое имя я не использовал

Я ещё раз отправил письмо, где ещё раз указал, что приложение неофициальное, мне эта торговая марка не принадлежит и апи у сайта создано специально чтобы разработчики использовали его на сайтах, в приложениях и т.д.

Пока ответ не прислали, но хотелось бы узнать, каковы шансы, что приложение разрешат опубликовать, или, если его заблокировали, то не стоит даже и пытаться что-то доказать?

Comment: скорей это название у них прошло как зарегистрированный продукт, вот и всё. Не пишите письма а исправляйте, все что вам указали в письме, мол извините - ошибся. Если будете писать мол это не так, вам просто аккаунт залочат и оревуар.

Comment: @shwarz-andrei, только что вспомнил, что в маркете есть неофициальное приложение для этой платёжки, правда его разработчик просто вставил webview и загружает там сайт платёжки. т.е. ничем от браузера не отличается. Так вот, название этого приложение -- 100% копия названия платёжной системы, иконка приложения -- тоже иконка платёжной системы. А описание скопированно с главной страницы сайта. Естесственно, у него очень много 1-звёздочных отзывов, но суть в том, что... Это приложение допустили!

Answer (score 2):

> Используйте только тот контент, авторским правом на который вы обладаете. Не используйте чужие картинки, видео или звуки, даже если ваше приложение будет способствовать развитию автора этого контента.
>   Будьте особенно внимательны к заголовку вашего приложения. От греха подальше — не добавляйте туда названия компаний или каких-либо популярных продуктов. https://habrahabr.ru/post/231009/

Будьте осторожны, обращаясь в техподдержку гугла. Вместо разблокировки приложения они могут из-за одного только письма заблокировать целый аккаунт.
Кроме общих правил для приложений есть ещё более конкретные рекомендации https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113474?hl=ru, причём на русском языке и в красивой форме, с примерами.

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ. В приложении не было картиной/звуков/видео с авторскими правами. По всей видимости, это произошло из-за названия(?).

Comment: Пожалуйста, посмотрите мой этот комментарий --  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558598/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-google-play-market#comment724507_558598. Хотелось бы узнать Ваше мнение по этому поводу.

Comment: Прочитайте статью , в плоть до комментариев. https://habrahabr.ru/post/231009/  . Если кратко, то тут как повезет.

Comment: ответили... В кратце -- не могут опубликовать приложение из-за спама в WebView. Что у них там в головах творится? Как думаете, допустим, если загрузить ещё 1 такое же приложение, но убрать внедряемый js, и если они его допустят. Можно ли в обновлении через несколько дней залить ту версию, которую они сейчас отклоняют?

Comment: Если приложение не прошло автоматическую проверку, то думаю что не стоит так делать. ( Да и в дальнейшем, в любой день могут заблокировать, особенно если станет чуть более популярней), это будет уже вторым предупреждением. Используйте другой способ реализации. (У меня случай был: через год только  заблокировали приложение из за тегов, причем без возможности редактирования т.е. занаго загружать апк и вся статистика, количество загрузок и т.д. по нулям естественно)